# Jinja has a "center" formatting option, but how about "right align"?

Tags: python, jinja2

Say I have

```
{% for key,value in adict %}
{{key}}:{{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I ensure that all of the keys are padded such that the output is

```
     something: 1
someotherthing: 3
  thelastthing: 2
```

edit: This is **not** a webpage I am working on, I am just getting string output for printing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`{{ key.rjust(20) }}:{{value}}` did the trick

I did not know you could just call python string commands from the box. If someone has a more "jinja" solution, using pipes, I will give the answer to that.

Comment: This is probably the right way to do it. If you need a more complex solution, just write a custom filter and apply it to the key. Something like `{{ key|myrjust }}`

Comment: Taking inspiration from your answer, I used `{{ key.ljust(20) }}` to create nice neat columns of text, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the build-in Jinja2 filter called [format](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#format). For example:

Left aligned string of width 20:

```
{{ "%-20s"|format(variable) }}
```

Right aligned string of width 20:

```
{{ "%20s"|format(variable) }}
```

Your case:

```
{{ "%20s:%s"|format(key, value) }}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer once I realized that the percent signs needed to be on the other side. ;-) I fixed (and up voted) it for you.