# How to do form label alignment in Jinja

Tags: alignment, jinja2

My question is very similar to this one
[Jinja has a "center" formatting option, but how about "right align"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404527/jinja-has-a-center-formatting-option-but-how-about-right-align)

Basically, I want the effect like:

```
     something: 1
someotherthing: 3
  thelastthing: 2
```

But instead of "key", I want to align "form.element.label". I tried to use the same rjust function. However, I got

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'wtforms.fields.core.Label object'
>   has no attribute 'rjust'

Comment: Do you need to use jinja for it?  Could you use CSS to align it instead?

Comment: @coralv  I see. Thx. I am very new to this stuff so could you give me a quick heads up how I can do it in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen your HTML, but I expect that one of [these](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) two [sites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) should have the info you need to right-align your element.

You'll need to do one of two things with your `form.element.label` as you put it into your HTML code.  You'll either need to find a way to identify the label (or maybe even the entire form that it's part of) so you can add some CSS that will be able to grab it, or you can add the CSS style code directly to that element on the page.  I'll give some examples using form alignment, but the same idea applies if you really want to do just the label.

Identifying the label or form with a CSS class

```
<style>
  .myform {
  float: right;
  }
</style>

<form class="myform" action="demo">
 <label for="demo">Demo</label>
 <input type="radio" name="demo" id="demo" value="demo">
</form>
```

Using CSS to align any label or form, causing all of them to right-align

```
<style>
  form {
  float: right;
  }
</style>

<form action="demo">
 <label for="demo">Demo</label>
 <input type="radio" name="demo" id="demo" value="demo">
</form>
```

Including the CSS in the code for the label or form

```
<form action="demo" style="float: right;">
 <label for="demo">Demo</label>
 <input type="radio" name="demo" id="demo" value="demo">
</form>
```

Make sure to check out those W3 Schools links, because there are other ways to do the alignment besides `float`ing the elements.  Hopefully this gives you what you need!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Actually I checked w3 school pages before and didn't find a solution. I have updated my question a little bit. Can you give me some more details of how to use "float" to achieve that effect? BTW, I actually have found I can use table(<tr> <td>) to achieve that.

Comment: I see what you're going for now.  Tables are one good way to do that, you could probably use `float` too, but it might be easier to put the elements into `div`s and right-align the text inside the `div` with CSS.